# React leaflet Marker position with latitude OR longitude indicator

Tags: openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I have been using react leaflet succesful with Int/Float coordinates like `[51.505, -0.09]`
however, i have longitude and Latitude indicator included on my coordinates like `['51.505W', '-0.09S']`.

**First options runs** well with this code.

```
const position = [51.505, -0.09]
        
render(
  <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>
        A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  </MapContainer>
)
```

**Thie second options** breaks with error  **Invalid LatLng object** How best can i handle this

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet, and by extension react-leaflet, expects latitude longitude to simple numbers, either in the form of an array of 2 numbers `[number, number]`, or an object in the format `{ lat: number, lng: number }`.  Coordinates like `['51.505W', '-0.09S']` don't fit that pattern.  But they can be easily transformed with a simple function that strips the letter character from the string and returns a number:

```js
function transformCoords(pair) {
  return pair.map(coordString => {
    return Number(
      coordString
        .replace('N', '')
        .replace('S', '')
        .replace('E', '')
        .replace('W', '')
    )
  })
}
```

This will take in an array of the format `['51.505W', '-0.09S']` and will return an array like `[51.505, -0.09]`, which can then be properly fed to a `Marker` position prop:

```js
const position = ['51.505W', '-0.09S']
        
render(
  <MapContainer ...>
    <Marker position={transformCoords(position}) />
  </MapContainer>
)
```

Comment: Thank you @seth for your input, those 2 will give you a totally different position, a more realistic example is `['36.837768E', '1.30315S']` vs `['36.837768', '1.30315']`

Comment: I recommend you read [Positive/Negative Latitude and Longitude values vs. Cardinal Directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536996/positive-negative-latitude-and-longitude-values-vs-cardinal-directions) - if you're using decimal coordinates, you should be using positive and negative, not cardinal direction character markers.  At any rate, you can always flip the sign for any coordinate that has a `S` or `W` attached to it.